# Elastic search performance tuning on AWS EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am newbie for server setup and performance tuning.
We have application, spring(4.1) + elastic search(1.7.3) + mongodb(2.7) + ubuntu 14.04. We have a local machine intel i7, 16gb Hard drive, another AWS EC2 (c3.2xlarge) 8 core 15 gb SSD.
Performance testing on local we were able touch 20k simultaneous request in 4sec. Same test on AWS is failing after hitting 600 mark. Threads starts going in waiting and then socket timeout exception.
Exploring bit more I tried directly testing Elastic search rest endpoint. Found elastic search start breaking after it touches 600 parallel threads.

I have few questions.

1. Does AWS core are not as good as intel i7 cores.
2. I have changed Ulimit unlimited in local and server both, is there any other setting at OS level i need to change.
3. Change ES_HEAP_SIZE to 8 GB. Though mongo dataset is not more than 100mb. Is there any other setting I need to check for ES.

Request for reviewer please put up comments before down voting if I can make changes in question, as my last to question are already downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you measure the bottlenecks and compare dev environment with aws?

- EC2 use server CPUs which are great for parallel processing, but their single threaded performance might be lower than the most powerful i7 - especially if you are using c3 which is based on a older CPU type. Try rather using c4 instance types.
- Make sure that you are provisioning the same amount of IOPS to your EBS as you require. Keep in mind, that a dedicated SSD will have a much higher IOPS than what is available to you in the cloud per default